Is it possible to find bandwidth without r0 in small signal hybrid-π BJT?
I am finding the bandwidth of hybrid-π BJT. This picture is from my tutorial. If I have gm,RB,RL,Cπ,rπ,Cμ, is it possible to get bandwidth without r0? As what I understand, if need Cin using Miller Effect, we need gain. But the gain depends on r0//RL.


It is common to ignore $r_o$ for BW in all cases when $R_L<<r_o$

Some time ago I did a complete study of the bjt ce, I think it might interest you, you can find it here: https://i.sstatic.net/JHXd6n2C.png (you have to zoom), (Sorry, the chosen bjt is the 2N4400 and not the BC547C.).
